# How to use ```gatsby-plugin-dark-mode``` in Typescript Gatsby

Tags: typescript, plugins, gatsby

### What I want to achieve

using 'gatsby-plugin-dark-mode' in Typescript Gatsby

### What I did so far

1. install 'gatsby-plugin-dark-mode' by
   `yarn add gatsby-plugin-dark-mode`
2. include 'gatsby-plugin-dark-mode' in gatsby-config.js

```js
module.exports = {
 plugins: ['gatsby-plugin-dark-mode'],
}
```

3. defined ThemeToggler component and import 'gatsby-plugin-dark-mode'

```
import React from 'react'
import { ThemeToggler } from 'gatsby-plugin-dark-mode'

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ThemeToggler>
        {({ theme, toggleTheme }) => (
          <label>
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              onChange={e => toggleTheme(e.target.checked ? 'dark' : 'light')}
              checked={theme === 'dark'}
            />{' '}
            Dark mode
          </label>
        )}
      </ThemeToggler>
    )
  }
}
```

### Then ...

`Could not find a declaration file for module 'gatsby-plugin-dark-mode'. '/Desktop/my-blog/gatsby-casper/node_modules/gatsby-plugin-dark-mode/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.`

### What I would like to ask & help

1. Am I overlooking something ??
2. Is 'gatsby-plugin-dark-mode' not supported with Tyepscript Gatsby ??
3. If using 'gatsby-plugin-dark-mode' with Tyepscript Gatsby is possible, tell me something what i missing here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you haven't yet, create a global interfaces file, called `global.d.ts` in the root of your project, and then add this:

`declare module 'gatsby-plugin-dark-mode';`

You can use this snippet for any package that throws that error and doesn't have published types.