# Could not find a declaration file for module 'gatsby-plugin-dark-mode'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I'm getting the below error, trying to import ThemeToggler from gatsby-plugin-dark-mode

```
module "C:/Users/Karim Elnemr/Desktop/my-gatsby-website/node_modules/gatsby-plugin-dark-mode/index"
Could not find a declaration file for module 'gatsby-plugin-dark-mode'. 'C:/Users/Karim Elnemr/Desktop/my-gatsby-website/node_modules/gatsby-plugin-dark-mode/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/gatsby-plugin-dark-mode` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'gatsby-plugin-dark-mode';`ts(7016)
```

also I'm getting this errors on the terminal for ever I try to install the blugin

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: gatsby-starter-hello-world@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"16.x" from gatsby-plugin-dark-mode@1.1.2
npm ERR! node_modules/gatsby-plugin-dark-mode
npm ERR!   gatsby-plugin-dark-mode@"^1.1.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
```

down below is where I imported the said plugin

```
import React from "react"
import { ThemeToggler } from "gatsby-plugin-dark-mode"

export default function ThemeToggle() {
  return (
    <ThemeToggler>
      {({ theme, toggleTheme }) => {
        if (theme == null) {
          return null
        }
        return (
          <label className="theme-switch">
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              onChange={e => toggleTheme(e.target.checked ? "dark" : "light")}
              checked={theme === "dark"}
            />
            <span className="toggle"></span>
          </label>
        )
      }}
    </ThemeToggler>
  )
}
```

need some explanation what dose it mean and why it's happening so I can solve it.

Comment: you are using typescript template for your react project ?

Comment: No, I didn't use any typescript!

Comment: it's weird  usually ask for types came with project in typescript
did you try "npm i --save-dev @types/gatsby-plugin-dark-mode"

Comment: it's really strange , share the file when you use the import lib please , am still wondering that there is a typescript somewhere

Comment: yes it's, I have shared the code where I imported, I really wonder what i might did wrong?

Comment: okey so let's see other way , weach react version do you use in this project ?

Comment: "react": "^17.0.1"

Comment: try to downgrade react version to 16.14.0 and did a npm install --force and don't forget the react-dom too

Comment: Okay, will try this and be back in while.

Comment: Thank you so much Borni.Mr, it's working now.

Comment: Great !! i resume the solution in separate answer and you can approuve it , to be useful for others who have the same issue ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to downgrade your react versions:
in your package.json

```js
   "dependencies": {
   ...
   "react": "16.14.0",
    "react-dom": "16.14.0",
    ...
    }
```

Then delete your node-modules folder
and run

```
yarn install or npm install
```

Answer (score 2):

The error on the install means that the library you want to install depends on react 16 while you have React 17 installed on your project

you can use this command
**npm i gatsby-plugin-dark-mode --legacy-peer-deps**

Comment: and I tried this option also still giving me Could not find a declaration file for module 'gatsby-plugin-dark-mode'.

Comment: it's normal @types/gatsby-plugin-dark-mode does not exist the module does not support typescript

Comment: I use "react": "^17.0.1"

Comment: You are using typescript in your project ? can you add webpack config to the question ?

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67015128/how-to-use-gatsby-plugin-dark-mode-in-typescript-gatsby

Comment: @MahaBenJebara He didn't use typescript !! custom.d.ts work only with project in typescript ^^

Comment: @MahaBenJebara i will vote your answer , this will be useful for those who used typescript in their project ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do : **npm i gatsby-plugin-dark-mode --force**

Comment: I have tried it, still giving me Could not find a declaration file for module 'gatsby-plugin-dark-mode'.